# Microsoft Dynamics Nav Web Services - Assembly BOM

Tags: soap, navision

I'm trying to create an Integration with Microsoft Dynamics Nav and want to edit assembly BOM's of items. I'm able to read an assembly BOM item by searching the line items number and then parsing the record ID to give me the parent item Number.
I now want to create an Assembly BOM, the SOAP web service has a create call but i'm unsure what to pass into the new line item to link it to a parent record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way would be to create a new Page with **Source Table** *BOM Component*. All fields that you want to fill should also be in that Page. Then this Page should be Publish as new Web Service.

In my Example the Name of the Web Service is *AssemblyBOM*. I changed the Example from the MSDN Articel [Walkthrough: Registering and Using a Page Web Service (SOAP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd355316(v=nav.90).aspx) to create to entries in the Assembly BOM:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using ConsoleApp1.AssemblyBOMWebService;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{ 
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        AssemblyBOM_Service service = new AssemblyBOM_Service();
        service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        //First Item
        AssemblyBOM bom = new AssemblyBOM();
        bom.Parent_Item_No = "10000";
        bom.Line_No = 10000;
        bom.Type = AssemblyBOMWebService.Type.Item;
        bom.No = "10021";

        // Additional Fields ..  

        service.Create(ref bom);

        // Secord Item
        AssemblyBOM bom = new AssemblyBOM();
        bom.Parent_Item_No = "10000";
        bom.Line_No = 20000;
        bom.Type = AssemblyBOMWebService.Type.Item;
        bom.No = "10025";

        // Additional Fields ..  

        service.Create(ref bom);

        Console.WriteLine("Press [ENTER] to exit program!");
        Console.ReadLine();            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Macfox. For now i've achieved it by going straight into the SQL db  but i'll look into this method. Do you know why the Parent_Item_No field isn't available when you publish the Assembly BOM page (36)?

Comment: The Field "Parent Item No." was put in the Page 36 by Microsoft.